# How to fix Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled errors

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008, msdtc

We are using transaction scope features of ASP.NET to manage distributed transaction for that we need to enable distributed transaction via following link:
[The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/)

Its works well with SQL Server 2005 and Windows Server 2003 but when it comes to Windows Server 2008 server and SQL Server 2005 we are getting following error, still we followed the same steps provided in above link:

> Windows Server 2008  + SQL Server 2005
>   + Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for
>   network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the
>   Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

Answer (score 4):

On my blog I discuss a fix: [Fix MSDTC (Microsoft Distributed transaction coordinator)](http://pongsathonkeng.blogspot.com/2011/02/msdtc-setup.html)

This post will help you how set setup and check communication of MSDTC between servers.
Please check:

- Network
- Firewall
- ACL permission

You can config your severs and test the MSDTC by using following tool.
DTCTester: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q293799

Comment: you can merge both of your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 has a different security model than windows 2003, and it's driven by xml file which contains a whole shedload of security entries. I've not went into it in detail, as yet, so all I can do is give you a start.

Select Admin Tools-> Security Configuration Wizard.
Find your current security policy (don't know where it is stored, but technet will tell you).
Go down the list, and ensure Distributed Transactions are checked. They are not checked by default.
Apply the new policy.

Be careful with using this utilty, as u could serious knacker your system, or open a security hole.
Hope that helps.
Bob.