# How to Suppress TransationScope's error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Facing this issue when I am using `TransactionScope` in , I want to suppress **this error only** and do not want to do any configuration (settings).

Error Message:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

Error Line:

```
_cacheLogic.UpdateCache<List<CustomEntity>>(Detail, CacheConstants.RM_CACHE_GET_DETAIL, cacheKey);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050512/how-to-fix-distributed-transaction-manager-msdtc-has-been-disabled-errors)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you wish to use `TransactionScope`, supressing the error would not suffice.
2. To use the `TransactionScope` in your code, you need to enable the `Microsoft Distributed Transactions Coordinator (MSDTC)` from the `Component Services` on your server .
   Here are the detailed steps to enable it: http://pongsathonkeng.blogspot.in/2011/02/msdtc-setup.html
3. Further, the error also indicates that certain network related access needs to be given to the MSDTC. For that you may look at Step #2 in the link above.

Also, [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/293799) is tool that would allow you to test you setup, afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

So you are using multiple data sources inside one transaction scope. When this happens, distributed transaction should take place, and in your case distributed transaction manager is not configured properly. As I understand from your question, you don't really want to fix this, and don't need distributed transaction to take place. Then you need to change your code, so that there are no work with multiple databases under the same TransactionScope any more. Suppose you have something like this:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope()) {
    var data = SelectSomeDataFromDatabaseA();
    if (data.IsFine) {
        InsertSomeDataInDatabaseB();
    }
    transaction.Complete();
}
```

Here you are working with databases A and B inside one transaction scope, but you don't really need to do it - just move code selecting database from database A outside transaction scope.

Note also that in some cases, distribution transaction may be started even if you work with the *same* database - this might happen if you work with the same database using *different* connections. If that is your case - avoid creating multiple connections and instead pass the same connection instance to all methods where you need that.